# How to handle sqlite3_exec error in C while deleting the database?

Tags: c, sqlite

I am trying to clear the database after printing the records from the database.But while clearing the database, few times sqlite3_exec is giving an error, due to which database is not getting cleared. I would like to know how to handle these kind of scenarios.

When there is any error while clearing the database, i retry to clear the database one more time. This is one option. I am looking for any other option which i can use for my logic.

```
errstr = 0;
rc = sqlite3_exec(test_db, "DELETE FROM EMP_TABLE WHERE id = 2", 0, 0, &errstr);

if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    printf("removing record  Fails %s\n", errstr);
    sqlite3_free(errstr);
}

errstr = 0;
rc = sqlite3_exec(test_db, "VACUUM;", 0, 0, &errstr);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
   printf("vacuum Fails: %s\n", errstr);
   sqlite3_free(errstr);
}
```

Whenever sqlite3_exec fails, how do i retry to clear database in a optimized way instead of calling same sqlite3_exec once again.

Comment: *Why* does it fail?

Comment: Not sure, the reason of fail. I haven't debugged the sqlite3 API

Comment: You print out an error message...

Comment: Setup a callback error log function and print the error code/message: https://www.sqlite.org/errlog.html. So you know what happened and find a solution for the specific error code/message.

Comment: sure.. I will put the callback function and debug. Whenever there is an error can i retry to delete the data from the database.

Comment: I debugged the sqlite error, the error is database is locked while deleting the records.